# Android @drawable/logos.png error logos.png is incompatible with attribute android:res

Tags: java, android, dart, flutter

I just about to make a splash screen, and i made it in VSCode instead of android studio because i'm using flutter as SDK. I manually imported the image (drag and drop) and change somethings in styles.xml and launch_background.xml (since it is the splash screen) and i got this error

```
E:\Git\kene\android\app\src\main\res\drawable\launch_background.xml: AAPT: error: '@drawable\logos.png' is incompatible with attribute android:src (attr) reference|color.

E:\Git\kene\android\app\src\main\res\drawable\launch_background.xml:0: error: '@drawable\logos,png' is incompatible with attribute android:src (attr) reference|color.
error: failed linking file resources.
Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
...
```

here is my styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
         Flutter draws its first frame -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

and here is my launch_background.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable\logos.png" />
    </item>
    </layer-list>
```

and I can make sure that the file name is correct and the file is located at /src/main/res/drawable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove .png from your file name inside the launch_background.xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
<!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable\logos" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate and show the code snippet to provide context?

Comment: There, I have added the relevant part.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the backward slash with a forward slash
@drawable/logos.png in launch_background.xml bitmap android:src attribute

Comment: same result, if i changed the backslash the error changed to not found error, and i found about resource linking on the internet that i still don't really understand. could it be because i was just drag and dropping the image to the drawable folder?

Comment: check if the image is present in the resources/drawable folder and not under drawable-xxhdpi or other such folders

Comment: yup, i can make sure of that

Comment: enter command + shift+o and enter the file name and paste the path here